# Performance issues using sql_variant to store data

Tags: sql-server

I have a Key/Value table I'm using to store data that can be either text or numeric, but nothing else.

In preliminary testing, I am seeing **horrendous** performance when applying citeria to the sql_variant column, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM MY_DATA WHERE  
MY_ENTITY_TYPE = 555
AND CAST(MY_SQL_VARIANT_COLUMN AS NUMERIC) = 2254
```

So obviously there is going to be SOME hit with queries like this, but I am seeing queries well over 10 seconds, with only a few thousand rows in the table.

Considering I am only going to be storing numeric or text data, would it be more reasonable to use a varchar(255) column?  This way, select performance should be fast, and I would just have to do a post select CAST to get the data into the proper data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two methods to solve this performance issue:

1. CAST the criteria value rather than the column:
   SELECT * FROM MY_DATA WHERE
   MY_ENTITY_TYPE = 555
   AND MY_SQL_VARIANT_COLUMN = CAST(2254 AS NUMERIC)
2. Add an index to a different column in the table and see if it magically fixes the problem.  For example, add an index to MY_ENTITY_TYPE, and despite not criteria being applied to this column, it cleared up the performance problem in my example.

Obviously, #1 is the better of the two.

Comment: But the example does NOT use "not criteria" (to use your somewhat confusing term). It uses the equals operator, in which case indexing the column really ought to help. Presumably you mean that adding the index ALSO improved performance when you use a slightly different query from the above, such as WHERE EntityType != @typeID.

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me, but key/value table sounds like the uber-general DB many people try at some point or another (I did!) and it doesn't work well at all.

Are you sure you can't predict the keys and define a table where the keys are the columns and the rows are the values related together?

Comment: This is to store custom user data that is unknown at design time, they will be importing arbitrary spreadsheets, etc, and the schema will be defined in metadata.

Comment: Forgive me, but your "answer" sounds like the sort of über-general advice many people try to give at some point or another! There are many scenarios in which using name-value pairs are *much* preferrable to "correct" relational tables.